# wpf eventtrigger usercontrol inside stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, eventtrigger

I have a stackpanel containing usercontrols with eventtriggers. These eventtriggers is used to select a usercontrol, which works just fine.

Now i want to make it possible to deselect selected usercontrol by clicking in the stackpanel outside a usercontrol. This is here my problem occur. 
I have tried to add an eventtrigger to the stackpanel, but it wont work when clicking in the stackpanel only when clicking on one of the usercontrols inside the stackpanel and furthermore then overrule the usercontrol own eventtrigger.

```
<StackPanel Name="DisplayArea">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Edges}" />
                <StackPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                    </EventTrigger>
                </StackPanel.Triggers>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDownPanelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </StackPanel>
```

I understand that this isn't the right way to do it, but i can't figure out how to.
Hope you guys understand my problem.

Comment: Try hooking to `PreviewMouseDown` instead of `MouseDown`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't made any difference.